# How can I fix e: undefined and timestamp undefined?

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem seems to be coming from line 1 and 2. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
function rentreceiptfromForm(e){
var Timestamp = e.values [0];
var amountreceived = e.values [1];
var rentalperiodbeginning = e.values [2];
var rentalperiodending = e.values [3];
var paidby = e.values [4];
var paymentamount = e.values [5];
var Leasee = e.values [6];
var RentReceiptTemplatefile = DriveApp.getFileById["1NOH5JzONYzbMFwBMVwL3Uu5ruEvoI_Vhs1pS7krWA8A"];
var PopulatedRentReceiptsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById["1hkgwbRgJfY_NDdCiW8MkeqpARWu1ozCh"];
var copy = RentReceiptTemplatefile.makeCopy(Rentalperiodbeginning +  Rentalperiodending +  Leasee,PopulatedRentReceiptsFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getID());
var body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{{Amountreceived}}",Amountreceived);
body.replaceText("{{Rentalperiodbeginning}}",Rentalperiodbeginning);
body.replaceText("{{Rentalperiodending}}",Rentalperiodending);
body.replaceText("{{Paidby}}",Paidby);
body.replaceText("{{paymentamount}}",paymentamount);
body.replaceText("{{Leasee}}",Leasee);
doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Did you create a form submit trigger for rentreceiptfromForm

Comment: if you are running it from the script editor then that's the problem because e is supposed to be filled with the event object from the trigger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.